# Car rotation help for a mini game project

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I have a mini project where i have a car that drives on a cylinder and is rotating around the cylinder. When i press left mouse click the car rotates to the left and goes to the left and when i press right mouse click it rotates right and it goes right. What i want is when i release the mouse click buttons i want the car to rotate back to face the forward direction of the cylinder and continue going forward along the cylinder i have a script that is working but it is not rotating the car back to forward direction.

```
    //THIS SCRIPT IS ATTACHED TO THE CAR

 void Update(){

 //CHECKS IF MOUSE BUTTON ARE CLICKED

 if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
 rotation = -1;
 } else if (Input.GetMouseButton (1)) {
 rotation = 1;
 } else {
 rotation = 0;
 }

 }

 void FixedUpdate(){

 //moves the car forward

 //rgb is the rigidbody of the car

 rgb.MovePosition(rgb.position - transform.right * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);



 // THE LINES BELOW ROTATE THE CAR TO THE LEFT OR RIGHT

 Vector3 yRot = Vector3.up * rotation * rotation_speed * Time.deltaTime;
 Quaternion deltaRot = Quaternion.Euler(yRot);
 Quaternion targetRot = rgb.rotation * deltaRot;

 rgb.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Slerp(rgb.rotation, targetRot, 50f * Time.fixedDeltaTime));

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are setting the variable "rotation" to 0.

```cs
Vector3 yRot = Vector3.up * rotation * rotation_speed * Time.deltaTime;
```

Which results to 0 and your object doesn't rotate.

I would recommend you to do something like this in your update method:

```cs
if (Input.GetMouseButton (0))
{
    rotation = -1;
}
else if (Input.GetMouseButton (1))
{
    rotation = 1;
}
else
{
    //Now when the rotation is positive, 
    //the object starts to rotate towards negative, but stops at 0
    //Same is true when the rotation is negative
    if (rgb.rotation.y > 0) 
    {
        rotation = -1;
    }
    else if (rgb.rotation.y < 0)
    {
        rotation = 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        //This needs to be added here to stop the object from rotating 
        //when the y rotation is already 0
        rotation = 0;
    }

}
```

Now it rotates towards 0 when you don't press anything. Also don't use `Time.deltaTime` in `FixedUpdate`.

Edit:

So I noticed that with this method it doesn't quite never return to 0. It gets very close but not close enough. By adding this to `FixedUpdate` the y rotation gets rounded to 0.

```cs
if (Mathf.Abs(targetRot.y) < 0.00001f)
{
    targetRot = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(targetRot.x, 0, targetRot.z));
}
```

Comment: This works fine, but it goes infinite to the right or left, i need when it's not pressed anything to go straight, and when you do press to go in the middle.

Comment: @BobiSinadinovski If I understood you correctly, the edited answer should now fix your problem.

Comment: So, my object that car goes on is cylinder and 0 position on cylinder is only 1 point on the cylinder, and the car has to rotatae whole way to go back to the 0 position, what i need i the car should always find new position of 0, in other words i'll have not to look for 0 position of cylinder, but whenever i turn then from the position of turning that should be 0.

Comment: @BobiSinadinovski So you want the car to go back to **position** 0 instead of **rotation** 0? Example: car starts at position (0,0,0) and rotation (0,0,0). Then the user rotates the car and the car moves going to pos(2,0,1) and rot(0,40,0). Then the user doesn't press anything. Car goes to rotation (0,-40,0) and moves until its back at position(?,0,0) and rotation (0,0,0). If this was your original question you should've expressed that better. I'd just recommend you to ask a new question with a better explanation on what you want.